# render the html-placeholder based on country

Tags: visualforce, html, html5, inputtext

How can i render the html-placeholder based on country? In the screen shot below, if the country is Canada, i want to display the html-placeholder as 'Enter Postal Code'

[image]

Currently this is the code I have. The output label is rendered based on Country. I want the html-placeholder to render its value based on counrty too.  So, currently for USA as well as Canada I have same html-placeholder "Enter Zip Code" , however i want to display "Enter Postal Code for Canada"

```
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.USA_Zip_Code}" rendered="{!country == 'United States'}" />
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Canada_Postal_Code}" rendered="{!country == 'Canada'}" />

<apex:inputText id="zipcode" html-placeholder="Enter Zip Code"  style="width: 40%;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-left: 71px;" value="{!acct.BillingPostalCode}" styleClass="slds-input DealerZip inputHalf reqInput" maxlength="{!IF(country == 'United States', 5, 7)}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use merge fields in the placeholder:

```
html-placeholder="Enter {!IF(country='United States',$Label.USA_Zip_Code,$Label.Canada_Postal_Code)}"
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I will try as suggested and close the question.